# How to replace only certain characters in Java?

Tags: java, regex, replace

I need to format a string, seperated by colons and a semicolon (specifically,

```
Apartment or Building Number;Street Address:City:State Postal Code (i.e. NY):Zip Code
```

and have it changed to

```
Apartment or Building Number
Street Address
City, State Zip Code
```

So far, I have

```
public class MultiLine {
public static void main(String[] args) {
   Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

   System.out.print("Please enter an address formatted as such: 'Apartment or Building Number"
           + ";Street Address:City:State Postal Code (i.e. NY):Zip Code' \nFor example, Building Room 012;123 Fake Lane:Somewhere:NC:28500 \nPlease enter your address now: ");
   String text = input.nextLine();
   String text1 = text.replace(';', '\n');
   String text2 = text1.replace(':', '\n');

   System.out.print(text2);

        }

}
```

This, however, doesn't really work, because it replaces all colons with a new line, when I only want 1 to be replaced. I'm not entirely sure how to use `replaceFirst`, because every time I use it, it says I cannot convert char to string, but this apparently isn't an issue with `replace`. I can't split the string, mainly because I haven't covered that at all. (nor have I covered the `replace` command but it seems to make the most sense.) I also have no idea how to use `regex`

Comment: Where goes the string `State Postal Code (i.e. NY)` ? I already asked you this question before.

Comment: `replaceFirst` requires a regex, not a character.  However, since `:` and `;` are not special characters in regular expressions, you can simply use a one-character string, e.g. `text.replaceFirst(";", "\n");`, and it will work.  With characters that _are_ special, you'd have to include a backslash (and you'd have to backslash the backslash), e.g. `text.replaceFirst("\\.", "\n");` if you wanted to replace a period character.

Comment: It is still there, Avinash Raj. I just shortened it to "State"

Answer (score 0):

see replaceFirst asks for string, so you can use it in this way :

```
text.replaceFirst(";", "\n")
```

Comment: Oh, so I have to simply replace the apostrophes with quotation marks?

Comment: "apostrophes with quotation marks", I didn't understand

Comment: I had text.replaceFirst(';', '\n') and that didn't work, but I changed it to text.replaceFirst(";", "\n") and that worked, in other words, I changed the ' (apostrophe) to a " (quotation mark)

Answer (score 0):

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    String text = "Apartment or Building Number;Street Address:City:State Postal Code (i.e. NY):Zip Code";
    String text1 = text.replace(';', '\n');
    String text2 = text1.replaceFirst(":", "\n");

    System.out.print(text2);
}
```